# Swift 5 Loop MP4 In UIView With Full Screen Controls

Tags: swift, loops, video, uiview, mp4

I've spent a few days trying different combinations of code I've come across on StackOverflow to no avail.

Here's the code I'm currently using to display MP4 videos (looped, no sound) within a UIView component.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class VideoPlayerLooped {

    public var videoPlayer:AVQueuePlayer?
    public var videoPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer?
    var playerLooper: NSObject?
    var queuePlayer: AVQueuePlayer?

    func playVideo(fileName:String, inView:UIView)
    {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "mp4")
        {

            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL)
            _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
            videoPlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [playerItem])
            videoPlayer?.isMuted = true
            videoPlayer?.preventsDisplaySleepDuringVideoPlayback = false
            playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: videoPlayer!, templateItem: playerItem)
            videoPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
            videoPlayerLayer!.frame = inView.bounds
   
            inView.layer.addSublayer(videoPlayerLayer!)

            videoPlayer?.play()
        }
    }

    func remove()
    {
        videoPlayerLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

Although this solution works to play and loop MP4s, it doesn't provide the user with an option to click the video for a full screen version (landscape rotation) with controls.

Any recommendations or light that can be shed will be most helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `AVPlayerViewController`. Apple has a tutorial on the subject in the Xcode help system. It's also available online. Check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos).